# Forticlient fcconfig .bat

Tags: batch-file, special-folders

I´m trying to make a .bat that executes Forticlient and import a backup with SSLVPN configuration, so the user only have to login with his credentials.

When I execute the .bat file it says Access denied, it opens Forticlient but doesn't import the backup file. I left you here the content .bat :

`@echo off`

`C:`

`cd \Program Files\Fortinet\FortiClient`

`start Forticlient.exe`

`fcconfig -m vpn -f <c:\Users\administrator\Desktop\2.conf> -o importvpn -i 1`  <------- This line says Access Denied (1)

`exit`

(1) I tried to open manually Fcconfig.exe but it says Access denied. I can't understand why doesn't let me type this command, because in the manual it says clearly type this lines in cmd and that's all. Here you have the [manual](https://docs.fortinet.com/uploaded/files/4652/FortiClient-6.0.2-XML-Reference.pdf), the page is 84 and 85.

If anyone could helpme let me know, thank you. Of course I want you to remember that I downloaded just Forticlient free, i didn´t paid for anymore services.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186649/discussion-on-question-by-if-thanos-was-god-forticlient-fcconfig-bat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy this into your batch file, change nothing else, but the password:

```
echo off
pushd "C:\Program Files\Fortinet\FortiClient\"
start "" Forticlient.exe
fcconfig -m vpn -f "c:\Users\administrator\Desktop\2.conf" -o importvpn -i 1
```

to run this for other users, where you will not know their username replace the last line with:

```
fcconfig -m vpn -f "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\2.conf" -o importvpn -i 1
```

Comment: Where is the password here?. Can you please explain this step "fcconfig -m vpn -f "c:\Users\administrator\Desktop\2.conf" -o importvpn -i 1"